# IntelliJ with SVN doesn't honour *.iws files in my Version Control ignored files list when I commit changes

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I would like to individually, locally exclude IntelliJ .iws files from my Subversion changelist however for some reason the settings I've configured to ignore files in IntelliJ don't seem to be applied as I'd expect them to be.

Is it possible to have my own ignored files in my own local version of the project and if so, can you explain why after configuring a host of files in IntelliJ to ignore my project still wants to commit modified files?

**Existing Configuration:**
As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7714491/977087) on the question ['IntelliJ and svn:ignore'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000512/merges-on-intellij-idea-ipr-and-iws-files) I configured my local ignored files in my project by going to the following locations in IntelliJ

> *Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files*

However as I mentioned, still end up with these files in my modified files list on each commit.

I use Maven to build my project/modules and IntelliJ version 12

Comment: What colour are the .iws files in the project pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the .iws file is blue, then there is no svn:ignore configured on it and that is why IntelliJ thinks that it will need to go on changelists.

You need to be able to right-click on the .iws file, and ignore it like this:

```
(click) `Subversion` -> `Ignore` -> `*.iws`
```

But the trouble is that you have checked in the file once already, and the ignore option isnt available, so you can fix this as follows.

Method 1:

- back up your .iws file
- make sure you have TortoiseSVN integration enabled with explorer
- in explorer, right click the iws file and choose: TortoiseSVN -> Unversion and add to ignore list
- commit via TortoiseSVN

Method 2:

- backup your .iws file
- delete it in intellij (confirm to delete from svn, it goes red and into a changelist)
- commit the change via IntelliJ (.iws file got deleted!)
- restore the .iws file
- now, this time DON'T add it to subversion - choose ignore it instead.

You want to see (finally) that the .iws file goes grey in the project pane (this means it is successfully set with svn:ignore) and then lastly you can ignore it in intellij config so you wont see it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just came back to this. You've instructed me to do what I should have done but avoided - I agree though, it's the answer I need to carry out. IWS files should not be versioned in Subversion. That's the recommended approach but I was trying to keep it as only a local change. I could delete it from subversion and make a separate change list but it's avoiding the issue. Agree with your answer. Cheers